# A puzzle about numbers which do not have 2 in their decimal representation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

I came across this puzzle recently which I hope people might enjoy.

Let $S(n)$ be the set of positive integers less than $n$ which do not have a $2$ in their decimal representation and let $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of the reciprocals of the numbers in $S(n)$, so for example $\sigma(5) = 1 + 1/3
 + 1/4$ .

- Show that $S(1000)$ contains $9^3 - 1$ distinct numbers.
- Show that $\sigma(n) < 80$ for all $n$.

Comment: The first part is quite easy, almost obvious. The second part is troubling me. Nice puzzle.

Comment: Indeed for the first part, just count how many ways you can list an (ordered) triplet of digits where none of them is a 2 and you don't have all 3 digits equal to 0 since your integer has to be positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part: Since $\sigma$ is increasing, it suffices to bound $\sigma(n)$ for $n = 10^m$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$. It is not too hard to see that $|S(10^{m})| = 9^{m}-1$, so if we let $T_m = S(10^{m+1})\backslash S(10^m)$, then $|T_m| = 9^{m+1} - 9^{m}$. We have
\begin{align*} \sigma(10^{m}) = \sum\limits_{k\in S(10^m)}{\frac{1}{k}} &= \sum\limits_{k\in S(10)}{\frac{1}{k}} + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m-1}{\sum\limits_{k\in T_j}{\frac{1}{k}}} \\
&\le \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{9}  + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m-1}{\frac{|T_j|}{10^j}} \\
&<8 + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}{\frac{9^{j+1}-9^j}{10^j}} \\
&= 8 + 72 = 80
\end{align*}
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the first part. Imagine that our number system only has the 9 digits $\{0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ (no 2). Then count to 1000 like we always do, except now in base 9. There are $9^3$ distinct numbers. Take away 1 for 0 (because the set excludes 0), and the result is $9^3 - 1$.

Comment: Now for the hard part... =) I'm probably just as troubled by the second part as you mentioned you were in a comment.

Comment: I'm thinking something along the lines of figuring out the LCM of all the numbers in $S(n)$ then normalise the sum of the fractions in $\sigma(n)$ but that's as far as I've got so far.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for the second part.** Consider the number of elements of $S(10^n)$ larger than $10^{n-1}$, and observe that they all contribute less than $1/10^{n-1}$. Obtain the appropriate geometric series with ratio $9/10$.

Comment: I was thinking something along the same lines, but are you sure you can come up with a geometric series with ratio $9/10$? When you extend the valid numbers that have $k-1$ digits to the valid numbers with $k$ digits, you can add anything as the leading digit except the digit $2$. In particular you can have a leading $1$ instead of a $2$. I'm not saying your idea and approach are wrong, it's just not clear to me how exactly to fill in the details. I think this question is hard enough that if you post a more detailed solution you'll probably get a lot of up-votes and an accept.

Comment: @user2566092: The leading digit can't be a zero either. The ratio 9/10 arises from the constraint on the remaining $k-1$ digits.

Comment: @user2566092: I'm on the move.  I didn't post a complete answer because I don't have the time, but I thought the hint might be useful for people who wish to figure the rest out on their own.  I'll do it when I get a chance.

Comment: I see Joey Zou has already beaten me to the punch. :-)